# How to reverse arrays while inserting them via the while loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, while-loop, reverse

With this function I generate needed ranges:

```
first_index = 0
last_index = 3
ranges = []

while first_index != last_index
  while last_index != 0
    if first_index < last_index 
      ranges << (first_index..last_index)
    end 
      last_index -= 1
  end
  first_index += 1
  last_index = 3
end 

p ranges
```

The output is:

```
[0..3, 0..2, 0..1, 1..3, 1..2, 2..3]
```

I need to revert the output of the nested `while` loop, after it finishes. So in this example, I need:

```
 [0..3, 0..2, 0..1].reverse 
 [1..3, 1..2].reverse
 [2..3].reverse (wouldn't make any different on this, though)
```

The output I would get is:

```
[0..1, 0..2, 0..3, 1..2, 1..3, 2..3]
```

Can I invoke `reverse` somehow in that function? `last_index` could be any integer. I used 3 just to shorten the output.

Comment: `(0..3).to_a.combination(2).map { |a, b| a..b }` returns the ranges in the expected order.

Comment: @Stefan Well thats a great solution in just a few seconds. If you could write an answer with a brief explanation, I would accept it and maybe this will help someone else as well, some day..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So the output I would get:
>
> ```
> => [0..1, 0..2, 0..3, 1..2, 1..3, 2..3]
> ```

This is exactly what [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) returns:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
a.combination(2).to_a
#=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

To get ranges:

```
a.combination(2).map { |a, b| a..b }
#=> [0..1, 0..2, 0..3, 1..2, 1..3, 2..3]
```

However, note that the documentation says: (emphasis added)

> The implementation makes **no guarantees about the order** in which the combinations are yielded.

So you might want to explicitly [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) the result:

```
 a.combination(2).sort
 #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: … and the sort *does* work because `Array`s are guaranteed to be compared lexicographically. (I think it's mentioned in the docs for `Array#<=>`.)

Answer (score 1):

If the order is critical, you could use an intermediary array.

```
first_index = 0
last_index = 3
ranges = []
sub_ranges = []

while first_index != last_index
    while last_index != 0
        if first_index < last_index 
            sub_ranges << (first_index..last_index)
        end 
            last_index -= 1
    end
    ranges << sub_ranges.reverse
    sub_ranges = []
    first_index += 1
    last_index = 3
end
ranges.flatten!
p ranges
```

It is a far shot, but on large number array manipulations become relatively expensive. You could rely more on numerical work. Alternatively, you just like this one more:

```
first_index = 0
last_index = 3
ranges = []

y = first_index + 1

while first_index != last_index
    while y <= last_index
      ranges << (first_index..y)
      y += 1
    end
    first_index += 1
    y = first_index + 1
end
```

Comment: A more idiomatic implementation: `(0...3).flat_map { |a| (a+1..3).map { |b| a..b } }` with `0` being `first_index` and `3` being `last_index`